# Erro ao conectar um banco postegresql com Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, linux, ubuntu

Eu estou tendo um problema ao utilizar o Laravel com o postgresql no Linux, ao tentar conectar com o banco de dados ele fala que não acha o driver do postgresql, eu já habilitei o postgresql no php.ini assim:

```
extension=pgsql.so
extension=pdo_pgsql.so
```

Essa é a Query SQL:

```
$usuario = DB::select('select * from usuario');
```

O Erro que o Laravel me mostra é esse:

```
"could not find driver (SQL: select * from usuario)"
```

Já instalei o driver do php-postgresql, já reiniciei os dois serviços apache2, postgresql e também reiniciei o composer.

A minha distro é o elementaryOS(baseado no ubuntu 14.04)

edit:
.env:

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=minha_db
DB_USERNAME=meu_user 
DB_PASSWORD=minha_senh3
```

database.php

```
'pgsql' => [
    'driver' => 'pgsql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'minha_db'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'meu_user'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'minha_senha'),
    'charset' => 'utf8',
    'prefix' => '',
    'schema' => 'public',
    'sslmode' => 'prefer',
],
```

Edit:
Graças a Deus consegui resolver, eu tentei instalar o pacote com o comando abaixo e o driver funcionou:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-pgsql
```

Antes eu tinha instalado sem especificar a versão e não funcionou:

```
sudo apt-get install php-pgsql
```

Comment: Imagino que por `php-postgresql` você queira dizer o pacote `php-pgsql`? Como você está [abrindo a conexão com o Postgres](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-pgsql.connection.php)? Uma forma de testar se a conexão está mesmo acontecendo é habilitar os parâmetros `log_connections` e `log_disconnections` no postgresql.conf, dar um reload no Postgres e ir dar uma olhada no arquivo de log. Outra forma é colocar um sleep longo no PHP depois de criar a conexão e ver no banco se ela aparece em um `select * from pg_stat_activity;`

Comment: Aparentemente falta-te instalar a driver, php-pgsql: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_php.htm

Comment: @nunks.lol eu estou usando o padrão do framework.@Miguel instalei o driver e no arquivo the pg_hba.conf eu fiz uma config mais ou menos assim: host    all         all         0.0.0.0/0          md5

Comment: Os dados de conexão já estão configurados no seu `.env`?

Comment: Sim, eu corrigi já, troquei de mysql pra pgsql e coloquei os credenciais certas.

Comment: Estranho... Você pode editar seu post e colocar o seu `.env` (pode omitir os dados de conexão) e o arquivo `/config/database.php`? Só pra ver como está configurado em ambos.

Comment: @Guh edite e coloquei la